# An error occurred while calling o91.getDynamicFrame. No such file or directory

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-glue

Using the AWSGlueServiceRole, I created a Glue job to map a parquet file from one S3 bucket to another. When I attempt to run the job, I receive the following exception:

"An error occurred while calling o91.getDynamicFrame. No such file or directory 's3://BUCKET/PATH/TO/FILE.parquet'"

According to my check, the file exists. My first thought was that it might be a permissions issue, so I tried getting the object using boto3 on my local machine and got the file back:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='BUCKET', Key='2022/05/24/08/PATH/TO/FILE.parquet')
print(pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())))

------------------ Output bellow ------------------
          id  val1           val2  val3
0     model2    0.612707     None  [[2.1931596, 1.5204412, 1.4174217, 1.6540076, ...
1     model2    0.972054     None  [[1.8610013, 2.1553798], [1.8610013, 2.1553798...
2     model2    0.526641     None  [[1.3793343, 1.430331, 2.1639223], [1.3793343,...
3     model2    0.927919     None  [[2.10741, 1.5591071, 2.1414866, 2.920107], [2...
4     model2    0.243281     None  [[1.2257551, 1.515327, 2.0952048, 1.1441619], ...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Being able to get the object locally doesn't mean there can't be a permissions issue between the Glue ETL job and the bucket. Or are you saying that this bucket has public access?

Comment: No public access, what permissions should I check for?

Comment: Might be worth having a read through this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/getting-started-access.html

Answer (score 0):

You need these permissions on the bucket and its objects:

```
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:Get*",
      "s3:Put*"
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>",
      "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET>/*",
    ]
  }
```

I agree that the error message is confusing and misleading. The reason is that, as a managed service, Glue first does a "List" action on the S3 location, and then feeds the results to `getDynamicFrame`. So when it receives the `AccessDenied` error (but somehow not showing us) and an empty "list", `getDynamicFrame` just simply raises the `No such file or directory` error. All in all, they should have done a better job on the error handling.

Comment: Is a `"s3:Put*"` action required if we just want to read the data and load it into dynamic Frame